# Webapi and normal methods in the same controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

With the introduction of the `Apicontroller` attribute in asp.net core 2.1, I wonder how do I get the api and normal methods to work in the same controller.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class OrderController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SaveOrder(SaveOrderModel model)
    {
        //...
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> CustomerOrders()
    {
       if (!User.IsInRole("Customer"))
          return Challenge();
       var customer = await _workContext.CurrentCustomer();

       var model = await orderModelFactory.PrepareCustomerOrderListModel();
       return View(model);
    }
}
```

I can call post method `/api/order/saveorder` but cannot run the `https://example.com/order/customerorders`.

> It shows an exceptions: InvalidOperationException: Action
>   '.CustomerOrders ' does not have an attribute route. Action methods on
>   controllers annotated with ApiControllerAttribute must be attribute
>   routed.

If I remove [ApiController] and [Route("api/[controller]")] on the controller level and instead put on the method level, then it surely works. still don't know if there's any better hybrid solution for these methods as i want to use this new ApiController feature.

```
[Route("/api/controller/saveorder")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveOrder(SaveOrderModel model)
```

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: `CustomerOrders` is a `HttpGet` method, how you send the request for both methods and why the GET request doesn't work?

Comment: What do you mean by **can not run**? Does not hit? Return `null`? What do you expect to get?

Comment: @ibubi sorry, i updated my post.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto customerorder is not httpget, it's a nomarl action method to return view

Comment: You cannot use `return View()` inside a controller marked with `ApiControllerAttribute`. You can only use either `BadRequestResult`, `NotFoundResult`, or `OkObjectResult`. What happened if you put `[HttpGet]` attribute without attribute routing provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying, that you cannot call `https://example.com/order/customerorders`. In your `[Route("api/[controller]")]` you define, that all Methods inside this controller will be available at `https://example.com/api/order/`.

So to call your method, you need to call `https://example.com/api/order/customerorders`.

If you want to stay with `https://example.com/order/customerorders`, you need to put the `[Route]` attributes at your methods:

```
[ApiController]
public class OrderController : ControllerBase
{
        [HttpPost("api/order")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SaveOrder(SaveOrderModel model)
        {
            ...

        }

        [HttpGet("order/customerorders")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CustomerOrders()
        {
           if (!User.IsInRole("Customer"))
              return Challenge();
           var customer = await _workContext.CurrentCustomer();

           var model = await orderModelFactory.PrepareCustomerOrderListModel();
           return View(model);
        }
}
```